# Реализация личного кабинета в MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Объясните принцип реализации личного кабинета для пользователей в MVC 3 веб-приложении.

Comment: Грандиозный вопрос конечно... хотя бы напишите что вам не понятно. Например: где хранить данные или как ограничить доступ, или что?

Comment: Как разграничить доступ для пользователей.
Например: как на этом сайте юда могу зайти http://hashcode.ru/users/5570/joe/edit , а сюда нет http://hashcode.ru/users/4863/wind/edit
Как это делают? Хоть в общих чертах.

Answer (score 1):

Рассказываю, как я сейчас делаю сам:

1. создаю еще одну вкладку - ЛК
2. в ней создаю вложенную мастер страницу
3. в там уже как угодно, с левой стороны навигационное меню по вкладкам, справа - окно с данными